# wikipedia leaving site image

Tags: html, css, svg

I want to make my website use the external link icon that Wikipedia uses.  It is an SVG that is displayed at the end of the link using CSS I believe.  The line they use for the links looks much like

```
<a class="linkout" href="
```

How do I code CSS or JS (preferably CSS) to add the image to the end.  Looking thru the Wikipedia source code I have yet to figure out how they do it.

Comment: I can't find a single instance of class "`linkout`". Maybe you mean "`.external`" Are you looking at a particular page?

Comment: yes it is .external, I am using link out on my page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just gotta follow how wikipedia does it :

http://jsfiddle.net/y89kx/

have to set a few `background` css styles to a certain class

### HTML

```
<a class="external" href="someLink">External Link</a>
```

### CSS

```
.external {
    background-position: center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), url(image URL);
    padding-right: 13px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Adjit's way, another way of doing it is by adding content after using CSS3:

```
.linkout:after{
    height:16px;
    margin:0 0 0 5px;
    padding:0 0 0 20px; /* Width of your image */
    background-image:url(/path/to/your/file.png);
    content:" ";
}
```

See this JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/eECTc/